# Smart trainer & CX bike compatibility

Tags: cyclocross, trainer, turbo-trainer

I have a **Kona Jake the Snake Frame (2001)** and is currently mounted with **Continental Gatorskin 700x32c** tires and **Shimano RS010 622x15c** rims. I was hoping to use this on a smart trainer. This setup will be used for software like Rouvy. I'm new to cycling and was hoping someone could help me with some questions:

1.) Is it safe to mount thinner tires on the bike? If so, how thin can I go.

2.) Will the weight of the bike be an issue in choosing a smart trainer?

3.) I'm currently interested in buying a Tacx Bushido since I found a cheap one on chainreactioncycles. On the Tacx website, it says that as long as you use their Tacx 29" trainer tire, you can fit the bike on the trainer. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: Welcome to the site. We avoid product recommendations because they are not universal and turn obsolete quickly, so I’ve edited that part out. Question one you will find some existing questions have good answers to if you search around

Comment: In the [product manual](https://tacx.com/support/manuals/trainers/T2780_Bushido_Smart_manual.pdf) it lists which tyre sizes (outer diameter) fit in which position setting of the resistance unit.

Comment: I understand, will take a note on that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I will try to answer as best i can without going into too much detail,

1 : With a 15c rim you can mount 23, 25, 28 and 32 tires [Sheldon brown Tire Sizing](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html)

2 : Bike weight, Tacx don't specifically list any info regarding bike weight, as the user of the bike on the trainer can vary, I doubt this will be issue unless we're talking excessive weight.

3 : Tacx recommend the use of their tire as it has been designed to run without overheating, a quick search on the Tacx website has the 4 different sizes listed for 40 euros (Doesn't sound to bad to be fair) [Tacx Tires](https://tacx.com/product/trainer-tyre/)

Hopefully this helps you out.

Comment: I'd definitely go for a special trainer type tyre because they have the best grip on a trainer's metal roll and they are made from a special harder compound to withstand that use. Road-type tyres are softer and use up the rolling surface quite fast.

Comment: Cheaper harder compound road tyres also work very well.
I use an old vittoria rubino that got a bit cut up after an unexpected off road adventure.  Has been serving me well on the turbo for years.

Comment: Thank you for the info!