# How to use cheap nut and bolt bike with a smart trainer

Tags: hybrid-bike, trainer

I have a cheap bike (CCM Capri bike link: https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/ccm-capri-women-s-hybrid-bike-700c-0711734p.html). I want to use this bike with Tacx Bushido smart trainer. This bike has nut and bolt for the rear wheel. No through axle or quick release.

I have below questions:

1. As the tire on this bike has a tread pattern on it. I want to replace it with an **indoor trainer tire**. Can you please recommend which **tire size** I should buy. Currently, I have **700x38C** tire (as shown in the pic below). I am looking at something like the ones shown in this link: https://tacx.com/product/trainer-tyre/
2. How should I use the device provided by the smart trainer (shown in the green pic) on my tire? Do I remove the rod by unscrewing the nut and bolt and use this device provided by the smart trainer?
3. Is there a way to convert this nut and bolt configuration to through axle?

I have already checked this link and did not find it useful for my case: [Smart trainer & CX bike compatibility](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/62151/smart-trainer-cx-bike-compatibility)

Bike tire right side:
[image: Bike tire right side]

Bike tire left side:
[image: Bike tire left side]

Tacx Smart trainer rod to be used with the tire:
[image: Tacx Smart trainer rod]

Tire information:
[image: Tire information]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the trainer? The critical detail is the attachment point where the axle get pinched onto the trainer. I have a trainer that will accept both nutted axles and a quick release skewer. If yours is similar you would not use the skewer.

Comment: If your bike is going to stay on the trainer - may as well wear out the current tyre before buying a replacement.  You can then swap and wear out the former front tyre.  Only then would you need a new one.

Comment: @mikes you were right! I tried my bike on the trainer and it did not need the quick release skewer. I was able to connect the bike directly and use the trainer. Thanks for the suggestion. It was very helpful.

Comment: @Criggie Even though the bike is cheap, I just bought it and don't want to ruin the tire. Everywhere I see that normal tires should not be used with trainers. The trainer tires are made to withstand high temperatures. Also, the trainer tires should not be used on the road. I see that you have marked the question as duplicate. The first part is definitely answered in that other question. But I can't find the answer to the tire size question anywhere. As you have closed this question, I guess I will have to post the second part of the question again.

Comment: @AmanSharma fair enough - SE prefers one question per question. 
1. you need a 700c tyre which TACX called "28 inch", which is measured as 622mm in the modern system.  Your current tyre is 38mm  wide, so its a 622-38.   
622 must match, width is more forgiving.   2. that's a QR skewer with ends that fit the trainer.  You don't have to use it, if trainer can take your existing wheel nuts.  Check manual.
3. Through Axle?  No.  That's the new modern stuff and would need a new frame.  Convert to QR Quick Release, possible but fiddly.  See https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/25957/

Comment: Do explore the search functions - we have tens of thousands of questions posted, so there's likely a chance someone's asked it before.

Comment: Finally I see there's some confusion from the tacx website - they only have one width of trainer tyre for each size.   There is a road tyre in 23mm width, but they also have a 29" MTB tyre in 32mm wide, which would be a better fit for your existing rim.   Bike tyre measurements are weird - 28" and 29" are the same size for this century's wheels.

Comment: Thanks @Criggie Your comments are very helpful! It clarifies a lot of doubts for me. I have upvoted the comments as they help me understand the solution better.